# Can´t access a radio button

Tags: c#, selenium

I have the HTML bellow and I want to click at the radio button with the input Name = optUsoTabaco. But I have not been successful.

```
<section id="bloco-cadastro" ng-show="vm.modo.edicao || vm.modo.novo" class="">
        <ul class="passos">
        </ul>
        <form name="formSimulador" novalidate="" class="ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-cpf ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid-date">
            <p class="aviso-campos-assinalados text-muted">Os campos assinalados com * são obrigatórios.</p>
            <h3 class="text-info titulo-bloco page-header">Dados do Cliente</h3>
            <fieldset class="simulador small">
                <input type="hidden" name="hidSimulacaoId" ng-model="vm.viewmodelsimulacao.simulacaoId" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
                <fieldset ng-disabled="!vm.viewmodelsimulacao.formularioEditavel">
                    <div class="row passo-1" id="passoUm">                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="row dados-solicitante">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row dados-estudo">
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label>Sexo *</label>
                            <div class="radio md-radio">
                                <label class="separador_direita  ativo"><input type="radio" value="F" ng-model="vm.viewmodelsimulacao.sexo" name="optSexo" required="" class="ng-touched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required">Feminino</label>
                                <label class="separador_esquerda "><input type="radio" value="M" ng-model="vm.viewmodelsimulacao.sexo" name="optSexo" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-not-empty ng-valid ng-valid-required">Masculino</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="has-error ng-hide" ng-show="formSimulador.$submitted || formSimulador.optSexo.$touched">
                                <span class="control-label ng-hide" ng-show="formSimulador.optSexo.$invalid">
                                    Valor Obrigatório
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-group">
                            <label>Fumante? *</label>
                            <div class="radio md-radio">
                                <label class="separador_direita "><input type="radio" value="S" ng-model="vm.viewmodelsimulacao.fazUsoDeTabaco" name="optUsoTabaco" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">Sim</label>
                                <label class="separador_esquerda "><input type="radio" value="N" ng-model="vm.viewmodelsimulacao.fazUsoDeTabaco" name="optUsoTabaco" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">Não</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="has-error ng-hide" ng-show="formSimulador.$submitted || formSimulador.optUsoTabaco.$touched">
                                <span class="control-label" ng-show="formSimulador.optUsoTabaco.$invalid">
                                    Valor Obrigatório
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </fieldset>
                <!-- ngIf: vm.botoesAcao --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-if="vm.botoesAcao">

            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </section>
```

I tried to access the radio button Named optUsoTabaco, with the codes:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#bloco-cadastro > form > fieldset > fieldset > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div.radio.md-radio > label.separador_direita.ativo"));

------ x ------        

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='bloco - cadastro']/form/fieldset/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/label[2]/input")).Click();

------ x ------        

 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='bloco - cadastro']/form/fieldset/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/label[2]")).Click();

------ x ------     

IList<IWebElement> radioBtn = driver.FindElements(By.Name("optUsoTabaco"));
radioBtn.ElementAt(1).Click();
```

In all these cases I got the error:  "An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element"
What am I doing wrong?

I´ve already tried to put a 10 seconds wait and it didn´t solve the problem

Comment: there are 4 check boxes which one you want to click ?

Comment: <label class="separador_esquerda "><input type="radio" value="N" ng-model="vm.viewmodelsimulacao.fazUsoDeTabaco" name="optUsoTabaco" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required">Não</label>

Answer (score 0):

all the xpath and cssSelector that you are writing are **absolute** and makes very less sense to use. Though they are correct. and I do not see any issue with them.

I believe there is iframe/frameset involve , for that you have to switch the focus of your web driver to that particular iframe.

Code you can try out :

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("xpath of frame")));
```

Comment: Can you please update us with iframe/frameset involvements?

Comment: I have a website and inside that a form using iframe.
The first thing I do in my code, after doing the login is SwitchTo the frame.

driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Id("IframeLegado")));

After that I fill some fields, but can´t do anything with this one.

Comment: see you are in an iframe  which has id "IframeLegado" , after all the interaction you have to switch back the focus of web driver to parent using this code : Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

Comment: and switch the driver focus to the iframe you want to interact now, makes sense ?

Comment: No, it doesn´t make.
I got to click using: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(), 'Não')]")).Click();

Comment: But it another webpage I´ll have a lot of "Sim" and "Não" texts labels.

Comment: but first you have to be inside the iframe then only you can use river.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(), 'Não')]")).Click(); this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Selectors

If you want to select Sim radio button, then use

```
 div.row > div > div > label > input[name="optUsoTabaco"][value="S"]
```

if want to select Não, then use

```
 div.row > div > div > label > input[name="optUsoTabaco"][value="N"]
```

Comment: Same error: An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: element not visible

Comment: Are you switching your focus to frame ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using JavaScript

```
IWebElement st_2 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("optUsoTabaco"));
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", st_2);
```